# VMware workstation 11

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

When trying to run vmware workstation, I get this error message. 
Is there a solution for this ?

```
vmware kernel module  updater 
stopping vmware service 
compiling : 
virtuel network device 
Unable to start services.
See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-5369.log for details.
```

Comment: Add the content of your logfile at http://paste.ubuntu.com/, [edit] your question and add the link.

Comment: are you using 15.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using VMware Workstation 11 on Ubuntu 15.04, the default vmnet network won't work unless you patch it. Here's a tutorial:

log in as root (e.g. `sudo -s`)
Enter your Root password.

Enter these commands:

`curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch`

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.SAVED
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmnet-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

I've tested it for 3.19 kernel and it worked like a charm.

[Source](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2511189)

Comment: Yeah I'm using Vmware 11 on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I'm using the exact same version and got it fixed by this method. It'll work.

Comment: but now Vmware asking me for license ky :(

Comment: well, VMware is a commercial product. You should buy a license key and insert it there. You can mark the answer as correct if it fixed your problem by the way